# Bot doesn't want to add roles on reaction

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want bot to add role and remove another one for those who reacts on message.

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    rUnauthorized=payload.member.guild.get_role(672473730114387968)
    rMember=payload.member.guild.get_role(672473925053055036)
    if payload.message_id==679223445258633216:
        if payload.emoji.name=='white_check_mark':
            print('Sucess!')
            await payload.member.add_roles(rMember)
            await payload.member.remove_roles(rUnauthorized)
        else:
            return
```

But when I am reacting to that message nothing happens(there is no anything in console as well).

Comment: what intents have you enabled?

Comment: intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!',intents=intents)

Thats all the intents I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making a mistake while checking the emoji. Try replacing this:

```py
if payload.emoji.name == 'white_check_mark':
```

with this:

```py
if str(payload.emoji) == '✅':
```

Alternative to the emoji, you can use the Unicode `\u2705`.

**Note:** You can also use `payload.emoji.name` instead of `payload.emoji`. It'll still work.