# Why can't i add reaction role for member?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to give the member a role when he adds a reaction

I tried do it like this

bot.py

```
import discord
import config

TOKEN = config.settings['token']

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.reactions = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = client.get_channel(config.channels['my_channel'])
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    member = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id = payload.user_id)

    if payload.emoji.name == 'emoji_name':
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name = 'role_name')
    elif payload.emoji.name == 'emoji_name_2':
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name = 'role_name_2')

    await member.add_roles(role)
```

config.py

```
settings = {
    'token': 'my_token',
    'bot': 'bot_name',
    'id': bot_id,
    'prefix': '-',
}

roles = {
    'role_name': role_id,
    'role_name_2': role_id_2,
}

channels = {
    'channel_name': channel_id,
}
```

also i tried to get the channel in a different way

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
```

but that didn't work either

Comment: because you don't have `intents.members` enabled

Comment: i added `intents.members` but it still doesn't work

Comment: did you enable them in the developer portal?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled them

Comment: You're probably making a mistake checking the emoji names. What string are you using for `'emoji_name'`?

Comment: The emoji names are league and stardew, these are names taken from discord

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65466198/11146632 let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is that I created my own emoji and I don't know how to copy them into the code. So I wanted to get emojis by their name

Comment: Can you check with other built in emojis? Then we'll know for sure that it's the problem with emoji names.

Comment: I tried to do as shown in the link you gave me with the embedded emoji but it still doesn't work

Comment: Try breaking it down. Are you sure you are getting the channel? The message? The member? The role? Print to see what the bot gives you, makes it a lot easier to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line the `'emoji_name'` should be `✅` or whatever it is. You can use `\:emoji_name:` in discord to get that or [this website](https://getemoji.com/)

```py
if payload.emoji.name == '✅':
```

**EDIT (Custom emoji) :**

First get the emoji using its id

```py
emoji_1 = bot.get_emoji(ID_HERE)

if payload.emoji == emoji_1:
```

Comment: I created my own emojis and I can't copy and paste them

Comment: ohh, I edited my code for custom emoji. The emoji can be from any guild the bot is in.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of the emoji to the full id of the emoji.

You can get it by sending `\:emoji:` in discord.

Comment: i tried to do like this `if payload.emoji.id == emoji_id` but it still doesn't  work

Comment: Have you tried `if payload.emoji == <:emoji:123123123>`?

Comment: Is there any error? And only that isnt working?

Comment: There are no errors. Only the issuance of roles does not work

Comment: What if you change to another emoji?

Comment: When I change emoji, the result remains the same